# What's The Best Source On Odin and Freya?

Tags: norse, odin

I would like to delve in Norse Mythology, but there is an extreme difference between the versions of it I come upon. I am most fascinated with the idea, that the Goddesses of Freya and Frigg are one being and Odin is actually Freya's consort. Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 6):

The best original sources for Norse Mythology are the [Poetic Edda](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Poetic_Edda) and the [Prose Edda](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Prose_Edda).   You can also find skaldic poems on a [website](https://www.abdn.ac.uk/skaldic/m.php?p=skaldic) curated by the University of Aberdeen.

As far as academic work on the subject are concerned, Mogk's [*Germanische Mythologie*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_f1YcAAAAMAAJ) seems to discuss about Frigg and Freya from pages 369 to 373, though the text is in german (Mogk is one of the scholar who identified Oðinn with Oðr, so I assume he has something to say also on the identification of Frigg with Freya); and more recently Stephan Grundy wrote a chapter on Freya and Frigg in [*The Concept of the Goddess*](https://books.google.de/books?id=8RfCB4rik7MC&lpg=PA59&vq=Frigg&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q&f=false).